# How to run shell command in specific path

Tags: shell, emacs

It is not convenient to run a shell command in emacs, though you can run a shell engine (eshell tern) or using it separately (zsh fish bash). So I think is there a way to run a shell command in specific file path directly?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Subprocesses will generally be run in the current buffer's working directory

Comment: Just like run `ls` on `~/file/path` through elisp or any other third-part library

Comment: Like `(let ((default-directory "~/file/path")) (start-process "ls" "*ls output*" "ls"))` you mean?

Comment: You might manually select the file path and type the shell command, not hard code it.

Comment: If refactoring the above into an interactive function is not something you know how to begin to tackle, perhaps you are on the wrong site.

Comment: Removing this to emacs stack overflow?

Comment: Probably yes, but you should probably figure out how to explain what you want in more specific detail before posting anywhere.

Comment: Look at [`(interactive "Ds")](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes)

Comment: Thanks, I'll forward another place ask for help.

Comment: This should be closed. Not only is it unclear but the same question was subsequently asked on emacs.SE.

Answer (score 0):

meta+x shell, then use cd to your path.

Answer (score -1):

You can run it as sub-shell:

```
( cd ~/file/path/ && ls )
```